# does .magento/services.yaml file exists in magento 2 open source?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, elasticsearch

i am trying to figure out how i can install elasticsearch plugin with magento open source, i foudn this page https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/services-elastic.html#elasticsearch-plugins but i can find .magento/services.yaml only in magento cloud, is there a .magento/services.yaml file in magento open source if yes then what is the path and if not is there a way to install elasticsearch plugins in magento open source? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.magento/services.yaml` is only used by Magento Cloud to specify the services used on your stack.

There is an ElasticSearch module is already built into Magento and there is also a popular module by smile.fr at https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite that gives additional functionality.

If you need to install the ElasticSearch server itself then you have a few options depending on your requirements:

- If you need it on your local development environment I would recommend using Docker. I myself am using the `elasticsearch:7.6.2` image,
- If you need this for you production/staging environment then:

  - If you have hosting specifically designed/optimised for Magento (such as Sonassi, Hypernode, Nexcess, MageMojo, etc.) they can set this up for you,
  - If you have managed hosting but it is not specifically for Magento I would suggest raising a ticket in your support portal,
  - If you have non-managed dedicated server or VM then you will need to install this yourself (may be worth asking support nicely if they can help you out) using this guide https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/install-elasticsearch.html

When the service is installed you can check it is running with the termianl command `curl http://elasticsearch:9200/` where `elasticsearch` is the hostname or IP address of the server. If it is running you should get something like this:

```
  "name" : "36b6fe61801c",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "zO9UbQAAQPmR8e0RgDN8Rw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.6.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "ef48eb35cf30adf4db14086e8aabd07ef6fb113f",
    "build_date" : "2020-03-26T06:34:37.794943Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.4.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Once the service is installed use the following guide to configure Magento to use it https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/elasticsearch/configure-magento.html